# CRM 2015 display attachment sub grid in custom entity form

Tags: attachment, subgrid, dynamics-crm-2015

I would like to create a sub grid in one custom entity form using attachment entity. But when I tried to build relationship between attachment and custom entity, I could not find new relationship button in Attachment customization. 
I know I can use annotation to display the attachment, but I think attachment grid would be perfect.

Could anyone please give me some ideas or suggestion?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that this isn't possible. You will either have to do something custom or just use annotations.

Comment: Simeng, basically the built in notes functionality already does what you need.  Files can be attached to notes and the notes section is basically a "subgrid" of these attachments.

Comment: Zach. Thank you for you replying. I knew notes can work well. Just curious and wondering if I can use attachment grid, that will be perfect.

Comment: But if it is a lot of effort, I may give up this way. Thank you, guys.

Comment: @Simeng, it would take a bit of effort to show only notes with attachments in a custom html grid. If you want to dig into it, let me know, and I can offer a little direction

Comment: @BlueSam, thank you. I may not spend much time on it. Please offer some direction, only for curiosity . It might be helpful for me and others who have the same question. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Something similar to http://blog.edgewater.com/2014/02/19/part-2-creating-an-editable-grid-in-crm-2013-using-knockout-js/ should be able to get you started